# Get significance level (p-value) of a model with quantreg

Tags: r, statistics, quantreg

```
set.seed(5)
library(quantreg)
d <- data.frame(x=seq(-5, 5, len=51))

d$y <- 50 - 0.3*d$x^2 + rnorm(nrow(d))

Taus <- c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9)

QR<-rq(y ~ 1 + x + I(x^2)+I(x^3), tau=Taus, data=d)
```

I need to find the p-value for the estimated coefficients of this model

Comment: `data` is `d`, right?

Comment: `summary(QR)` gives the confidence intervals

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Il like your nice & complete first post.  Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914192/r-package-quantreg-extract-p-values

Comment: Also maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052351/quantile-regression-and-p-values-getting-more-decimal-places

Comment: `sapply(summary(QR, se="boot"), '[', "coefficients")` in case you wonder why the linked dupe won't work in your case

Comment: @NelsonGon yes data=d, which is the data frame of the variables

Comment: @jay.sf yes only the confidence interval but I need more info about the parameters sign and model as well

Comment: run code comments above

Comment: @wibeasley thankxx it do help